# java.sql.ResultSet.next() method takes 3 seconds to fetch 1 record

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a problem with performance while querying SQL-Server from a Java program. According to the logs, I found the query itself is taking a expected amount of time. However, the call to `resultset.next()` seems to take an equal amount of time (about 3 seconds).

```
long nextBegin = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(!resultset.next()) {
    break;
}
logger.info("next cost = "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - nextBegin));
```

There is the logs:

```
[16-01-04 10:47:34]  INFO SqlExecutor:356 - next cost = 3575
```

Any ideas on this problem? Thanks~

NOTE:Setting `fetchSize()` did not solve this problem. As checked directly in SQLServer, there's only **one row** returned by that statement.

Comment: please provide your query...

Comment: are you using `selectMethod=direct` or `selectMethod=cursor` in your JDBC connection?

Comment: @Devart I really sorry about that.But I'm not allow to share by the corperation that I work for.The query is something like:"select column1, column2 from subquery inner join subquery where condition".

Comment: @Jan selectMethod=cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `selectMethod=cursor`, your `executeQuery ()` will **open** the Cursor and each `next ()` will **fetch** data from the cursor. Which is an I/O operation just like the initial `SELECT`.

Try running the query with `selectMethod=direct` once for comparison.

Please also record the execution time for your query in SQL Server Management Studio and check the execution plan.

Comment: It work.Thanks a lot~